# How do "infinite zones" in induction cookers work?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, appliances

I'm considering switching from ceramic to induction. I noticed that several producers (e.g., Electrolux, Bosch and Siemens) advertise something like "infinite zones", where the size of an induction zone is automatically adjusted to the size of the pot.

How are "infinite zones" achieved? Do they deliver what they promise or are they just marketing BS? I'm worried that "infinite zones" is euphemism for "let's inject a lot of power in a very tiny surface, 'cause customers won't notice".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this means coil sections are added and removed to couple efficiently to the pot currently in use, monitoring whether power is being drawn or not. It is a bit nicer than having to be as aware of minimum/maximum pot radius for each inductor, which requires a bit if attention on my induction range.

Pick your price/features trade-off...

(I do like induction, generally; it behaves much more like gas in its immediate controllability, and you can do silly tricks like cooking with a paper towel between stove and pot to catch splashes... but remember that it probably *will* require a few hundred more dollars to replace nonmagnetic pots.)